# как правильно обработать исключения в python3?

Tags: python-3.x, исключения, try

Вопрос в следующем есть код:

```
a = input("Введите первое число")
b = input("Введите второе число")
try:
    var1 = int(a)
    var2 = int(b)
except:
    print("Это не цифра")
```

как правильно указать в except в какой именно переменной ошибка: var1,var2 или обе? сделать несколько try  или парсить traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делать несколько try..except. Парсить трейсбэк не получится, потому что никакого трейсбэка не будет.

Comment: я имел ввиду через модуль traceback ( print(traceback.format_exc()) )